# EditText switch keyboard type on first focus

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have an EditText with a numerical value, and the inputType set to `number`. When I click on it, it opens the keyboard with the number layout, and after 1 second it switches to the full alphabetical keyboard. If I then select again the EditText with the keyboard already opened, it returns to the correct number layout. 
If I close the keyboard and open it again, I get the same problem again.

I have no idea why.

Here is the EditText :

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et_reservation_quantity_picker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
android:background="@null"
android:gravity="center"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxWidth="80dp"
android:minWidth="25dp"
android:text="1"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

It is inside a ListView.

Here is the code (it is in C#, sorry) :

In the GetView (I do not recycle the views) :

```
EditText etQuantityPicker = ((EditText)v.FindViewById (Resource.Id.et_reservation_quantity_picker));
etQuantityPicker.AddTextChangedListener (new SingleTextWatcher (item, _vm, etQuantityPicker));
etQuantityPicker.Text = item.Quantity + "";
```

And the listener :

```
class SingleTextWatcher : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
    {
        ReservationCellViewModel _item;
        ReservationsModificationViewModel _vm;
        EditText _etQuantityPicker;

        public SingleTextWatcher(ReservationCellViewModel item, ReservationsModificationViewModel vm, EditText etQuantityPicker)
        {
            _item = item;
            _vm = vm;
            _etQuantityPicker = etQuantityPicker;
        }

        public void AfterTextChanged (IEditable s)
        {
            string currentValue = s.ToString();
            int workingInt;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue))
            {

            }
            else if(int.TryParse(currentValue, out workingInt))
            {
                _item.Quantity = workingInt;
                if(_item.Stock > 0 && _item.Quantity>_item.Stock)
                    _item.Quantity = _item.Stock;
            }
        }

        public void BeforeTextChanged (ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        public void OnTextChanged (ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: can u post the `EditText` portion of ur `layout`

Comment: one more thing post `Adapter's getView()` method

Comment: I've added the code if it can help you.

Comment: actually I don't know about `c#` regarding syntax i'll post an answer if that helps u

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know about `C#` u can use a `ViewHolder` class

`during the scrolling of ListView` **findViewById()** `(inflated layout's children is inflated for a row of listview)` is called frequently, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for `recycling`, you still need to `look up the elements and update them`. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the `view holder design pattern`.

A ViewHolder object stores each of the `component views inside the tag field of the Layout`, so you can `immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly`. First, you need to create a class to hold your exact set of views.

For more info [Visit here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: I know how to use recycling, I don't do it here because in C# an object can have multiple event for the same thing, so when I reuse an edittext, it would have 2, 3 or more times the same event. (and in this case, I won't have more than a few items, so it wouldn't matter)